# shell concat directory and interpret caractere

Tags: bash, shell, path, interpreter

I try to loop in a directory to read file (*.pem)

i MUST USE path="/opt/test" . How concat path with *.pem (all the file in the directory with the extension pem)

```
for fichierCourant in $path/(*.pem) or "$path/*.pem" or `$path/*.pem` or 
'$path/*.pem'
do
```

..
done

Nothing works?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try `$path/*.pem` ?

Comment: if i do `$path\*.pem` it works for interpretationg  it  read file but can't anymore recognize in the file commande Certificat although there were recognize using directly   sh ./myshell.sh /opt/test

Comment: $path/*.pem it works if i use directly sh but i use c++ before with execve

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: If `$path/*.pem` (with a forward slash `/`, not a backward slash `\\`) works, then your problem is solved. If your problem is wider, I suggest editing your description with the specific command-line your execute.

Answer (score 0):

when path can contain a space or tab character must be between double quotes

```
for fichierCourant in "$path/"*.pem; do
```

Answer (score 0):

Try without any quote, this works if none of the files does not contains any space.

```
for file in $path/*.pem
do
    echo $file
done
```

With double quotes "$path/*.pem", though expands but consider all files as a single variable.
Additional Info:
'Single quote' : doesn't expands the variable
`backtick (or) backquote`: consider the content as a command